# Powershell MongoDb - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type MongoDB.Driver.ProjectionDefinition`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]'

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I am exporting MongoDB data from a collection into a file using Get-MdbcData. I am selecting fields from the collection using the parameter -Project with a string variable $FieldAttributes that lists either one or multiple fields to select and should have the format: @{_id=0; customer_id=1; account_status=1}

```
Get-MdbcData -Collection $MyColl -Project $FieldAttributes
```

Below is the code with the function that outputs the expected format of $FieldAttributes above.

```
function Format-ColumnSelect {
    param(
        [string[]] $Columns
    )
    $results = @{}
    $Columns = "_id," + $Columns
    try {

        foreach($a in $Columns -split ",") {
                if ($a -eq "_id") {
                    $results[$a]=0;
                }
                else {
                        $results[$a]=1;
                     }
        }
        return  HashConvertTo-String($results)
    } catch {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.GetBaseException().Message
    } finally {
    }
}
$FieldAttribute = "customer_id,account_status"
$FieldAttributes = Format-ColumnSelect -Columns $FieldAttribute
Connect-Mdbc $Url $Database $CollectionName -CollectionVariable MyColl;
Get-MdbcData -Collection $MyColl -Project $FieldAttributes  | Export-MdbcData $Path -Append;
```

When executed, I get the error:
*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type MongoDB.Driver.ProjectionDefinition`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]'.*

If I hard code the projection expression, *@{_id=0; customer_id=1; account_status=1}*, it works as expected but errors out with the variable.
How do I cast $FieldAttributes to the expected type? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the projection expression to: *"{_id:0, customer_id:1; account_status:1}"* and assigned the contents between the bracket to the variable $output instead of $FieldAttributes to differentiate from the input $FieldAttribute. The updated code that works is below:

```
$FieldAttribute = "customer_id,account_status"
$output = Format-ColumnSelect -Columns $FieldAttribute
Connect-Mdbc $Url $Database $CollectionName -CollectionVariable MyColl;
Get-MdbcData -Collection $MyColl -Project "{$output}"  | Export-MdbcData $Path -Append;
```